# Json not storing data as array php laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to store data in my laravel app like this

```
{"option":["Spoilers","Spam","sadasdas"],"additional_info":["sdasdas","asdasdas","sdasdas"]}
```

Or

```
{
"option":
["Spoilers","additional_info":"sdasdas","asdasdas","sdasdas"],
["Spoilers","additional_info":"sdasdas","asdasdas","sdasdas"],
}
```

Or something nearer to this

For this I have done this in my controller

```
 $json = ['option'=>$request->input('option'), 'additional_info'=>$request->additional_info];
 $comment->report = $json;
 $comment->save();
```

this option data I am getting is from multiple checkbox 
At once only one checkbox can be checked and submit 
but when I submit that using two times one by one it stores the latest one not both

In my Model I have done this

```
protected $casts = ['report'=>'array'];
```

Comment: Welcome, what exactly is your question? How to store things as array or json, or how to get your checkboxes right?

Comment: See at the top I have post the output I want

Comment: `$json` does not contain a json array. It contains a php array. You should run  `json_encode($json)` on it to do so.